# Preventing Rails from generating a log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 7
```

Is there a setting that would prevent Rails from generating a log file? As far as I can tell, the only thing I can do in the environment file, is change the log level, but not prevent a log file from getting created.

I understand that the log information is useful, but I have a specific reason not to want to generate a log file.

Answer (score 0):

Can You try adding below line to environments/(env_name).rb.

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

With this, Rails didn't create log file (verified for development.rb -> this file was absent after adding above config)